# GitLab CI: How to print an error message and exit?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want my GitLab-CI job to exit in case of a failure and print out an error message.

This is my script:

```
before_script:
    - |
      if [ -n "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" ]; then
        echo -n "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" | grep -qE '^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-(alpha|beta|rc|ALPHA|BETA|RC)[0-9]*)?$'
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
          >&2 echo "Invalid release TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
          exit 1
        fi
        echo "CI_COMMIT_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
        # remove the "v" prefix
        export GIT_TAG_VERSION=$(echo "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" | sed -r 's/^v//')
      fi
```

While the job correctly fails, the error message is not included in the job log:

```
$ /pre_build_script.sh
$ if [ -n "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" ]; then # collapsed multi-line command
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I want the output to be:

```
$ /pre_build_script.sh
$ if [ -n "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" ]; then # collapsed multi-line command
Invalid release TAG: ABC
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html this should work but the echo text is just swallowed - no matter if I print to `stdout` or `stderr`.

How can I print a message that shows up in the job log?

Comment: have you tried calling `echo` without redirecting (without `>&2` or `>&1`)?

Comment: Can you change the exit code to make sure that it really does enter the `if`, since the first `echo` is also not showing